# Hadronization time

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, hadronization

In the process of hadronization what is the characteristic time? I was thinking about at the inverse of $\Lambda_{\rm QCD}$ but can also be a dependence from $\sqrt{s}$. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two quick refs are [this](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-018-6459-8) and [this](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0954-3899/41/7/075105).

In natural units, ${1\over \Lambda_{QCD}} \sim 0.7$ fm, so the natural time unit here is fm/c.

A typical hadronization time is 0.4 fm/c , all the way to 0.7 - 1.3 fm/c.

Recall
$$
\hbox{fm/c} \sim 3 \cdot 10^{-24} s,
$$
so, since the lifetime of the top quark is only ~ $5 \cdot 10^{-25}$s,  it lacks the time to hadronize!

When you have lots of energy, *s*, in the rest frame of each hadronizing quark, the time is the same as above. If you wished to Lorentz dilate it, however, for whatever reason, it stretches…

Comment: Thank you so much!